# Nuget restore prompts with "this app can't run on your PC"

Tags: nuget

Suddenly the nuget restore command started to fail with "this app can't run on your PC" message. Command from cmd:

```
nuget.exe restore MySln.sln
```

The error:

[image]

Also there is an 'access denied' message in console:

[image]

I have VS 2017, Windows 10. Can't figure out what happened. Nuget clear cache doesn't help. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I downloaded a new nuget.exe from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and everything got working.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Someone updated a build agent's system-wide available install of NuGet with a broken EXE causing all nuget operations to fail. Just grabbed a copy off NuGet's site and was back up and running.